# Network using electrical wiring

Tags: networking, powerline-networking, wiring

Does anyone have experience with running a network over the electrical wiring in home? What product are you using? at what speeds? Are there extension to these kind of systems, for using TV, HDMI or audio?

In my home it is not possible to get a UTP cable to the rooms my computers are in and the wireless connections are too bad to use because of concrete floors and walls.

Comment: As a side note, the broadband over powerlines specification commitee (forget name) has finally passed a proposal. So hopefully we will start to see more equipment for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I've not personally had any experience with these, I've known a few people who had good experience with [NetGear's Powerline Ethernet Adapters](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/powerline-and-coax/).

Advertised as up to 200mbps (but with a 10/100 output).  But I'm sure it depends on your wiring.

Comment: The 200mbps claim is usually 100 each way (100Mbps full duplex and as your wiring acts as a hub not a switch this will not work if you have more than two adaptors). Most claim 85Mbps. As with wireless networks you won't see the full quoted speed in all but perfect conditions, though it'll be perfectly good for Internet access and I've seen a number of reports of SD video streaming flawlessly (I'm not sure about higher definition video streams) with this sort of network kit.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linksys (Cisco) PowerLine here without problem.

Was using it for LAN (while new machine was in another room), now just to link to ADSL router sitting on the master socket (for better performance).

I didn't do any significant speed checking, while computer was in the other room, but was certainly getting LAN type speeds with just a few milliseconds latency.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently bought th "Max Value 85 Mbps Home Plug Double Unit Pack" from Amazon [£41.99] and tested it successfully throughout the house and even into the garage (where my Linux Server will eventually reside). Setup was a snap (without the supplied software) and works with my multi-OS network without any problems.

Not sure of the speed but I was able to send some quite large video files over to the Linux box without thinking "This is taking longer than when it was hard wired to the router".